# A/the girl in question

Tags: grammaticality, articles

Is it somehow possible to use an indefinite article before a word which is adjacent to 'in question'?

For example, does 'A little car in question now stood outside the front door' make sense?

Doesn't 'in question' eliminate any possibility for 'a' to appear?

Comment: I can't find anything authoritative, but, though it sounds odd to my ears and I'd always use say 'one of the cars in question', there are  1 350 000 Google hits for "a car in question" and the first few all seem relevant and in reasonably well-written articles. Adding a modifier ('little') makes it sound even odder, though. // This is one where (a) a usage panel would probably be well divided on acceptability and (b) a usage panel probably hasn't been called in.

Comment: 'a' is fine, I feel, because, ...now stood outside the front door' gives enough emphasis, that 'the' could give. If one reads it as, "The little car in question now stood outside the front door' make sense?", one may feel too much has been talked about 'little car'.

Comment: Surely it has to be _the_, meaning 'the car we have just been talking about'?

Comment: If the topic of conversation involves multiple girls (or cars), then *a girl in question* would be quite understandable. It depends on how many are being discussed. (But cars don't normally *stand*, so that example is odd for a different reason.)